# Laravel validation checkbox

Tags: php, validation, laravel, checkbox

I am using the laravel register function to register a user. I added a checkbox where the user needs to accept the terms and conditions. I only want the user to register when the checkbox is checked. Can I use the 'required' validation in laravel? This is my validation function:

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'checkbox' =>'required',
    ]);
```

When I use the function like this, laravel gives the required error for the checkbox even if it is checked.

This is the html of the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="option" value="{{old('option')}}"><label for="option"><span></span> <p>Ik ga akkoord met de <a href="#">algemene voorwaarden</a></p></label>
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: What does your form look like? Did you check the actual post data in dev tools? Probably the html is wrong so the data isnt being posted. Top tip - if you are using a modern IDE, install xdebug and set a breakpoint

Comment: It will work, just be sure the input value will not be an empty string or false. And 'checkbox' =>'required' is ok as long as the key is the value of the input name attribute.

Comment: Thanks man! Can you post this as an answer? This way I can accept it and upote it

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use the [`accepted`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-accepted) rule.

> The field under validation must be yes, on, 1, or true. This is useful for validating "Terms of Service" acceptance.

Sample for your case:

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
    'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
    'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    'checkbox' =>'accepted'
]);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Terms of Service checkboxes.

Comment: This bypassed the server-side terms accepting validation if post is made manually.
The solution is to put accepted first then required.

Answer (score 8):

It will work, just be sure the input value will not be an empty string or false. And 'checkbox' =>'required' is ok as long as the key is the value of the input name attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I just had a big frustration, because the code i'm using returns the checkbox value as a boolean value.

If you have a similar situation you can use the following rule:

```
[
 'checkbox_field' => 'required|in:1',
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use  **required_without_all** for checkbox :

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'checkbox' =>'required_without_all',
    ]);
```

Refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $datos=$request->validate([
            'name'        =>'required|max:60',
            'descrip'   =>'nullable|max:255',
            'finish'    =>'nullable', //this is the checkbox
            'urgent'      =>'required|numeric|min:0|max:2',
            'limit'  =>'required|date-format:Y-m-d\TH:i'
        ]);

        
        if(isset($datos['finish'])){
            if ($datos['finish']=="on"){
                $datos['finish']=1;
            }
        }else{
            $datos['finish']=0;
        }
        $tarea=Tarea::create($datos);
        return redirect()->route('tarea.index');

    }
```

Comment: Can you share a bit "text" with your code?